# Не работает код, укажите ошибку

Tags: c

Вот условие: Элемент матрицы называется локальным минимумом, если он строго меньше всех имеющихся у него соседей. Подсчитать количество локальных минимумов заданной матрицы размером 10 на 10. Найти сумму модулей элементов, расположенных выше главной диагонали.

```
#include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <math.h>
     #define n 10
     int main(){
        int mas[n][n];
        int locMin = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                mas[i][j] = rand() % 100 - 10;
                printf("%d/n", mas[i][j]);
                }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if( (mas[i][j] < mas[i][j-1]) && (mas[i][j] < mas[i][j+1]) && (mas[i][j] < mas[i+1][j]) && (mas[i][j] < mas[i-1][j])){
                    printf("String %d column %d min = %d", i + 1, j + 1, mas[i][j]);
                    locMin++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d",locMin);
       
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
                sum += abs(mas[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("Sum of the elements above the main diagonal = %d ", sum);
                
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Элементы в нулевой/последней строке/столбце сравниваете с несуществующими соседями.

Comment: `man srand`. почитайте